# ajax post to external database from Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to insert data from a form built with Ruby on Rails to my SQL Server database. I have connected my database correctly and can pull data from it. I am now trying to post back to it. I am needing help with figuring out how to get the data from the form into the correct columns in my table in the database.

My ajax:

```
  <script>
$('#Favorites').on('submit',function(event){
    var $form = $(this),
    data = $form.serialize();
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/welcome/insert';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(){
            
            alert('Your form has been successfully submitted!');
            document.getElementById('Favorites').reset();
            window.location.reload();
        },
        fail:function(){
            alert('something went wrong...try again');
        }
    });
 return false;
 });

</script>
```

My controller function:

```
def insert
    @ipinsert=Ipdw.connection.execute("insert into [DB_Test02].[dbo].[My_Table] (Report_Name,Report_Link)
  values ('I am cool','www.google.com')")
  end
```

Currently I just have a dummy insert statement here to make sure that I can insert into the tables and I can. I just need to know how to break out the form values sent to the controller and how to tell Rails what table and columns to put those values into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails will [format the data for you](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters). In controller like this:

```
{'Report_Name': 'some name', 'Report_link': 'www.example.com'}
```

and will be accessible via the `params`.

Your job is now to format the data correctly for the manual execution of the SQL query.

```
insert_values = "('%s', '%s')" % params['Report_Name'], params['Report_link']
@ipinsert=Ipdw.connection.execute("insert into [DB_Test02].[dbo].[My_Table] (Report_Name,Report_Link) values #{insert_values}")
```

Answer (score 0):

For the problem of which table to add to your DB server you could specify this in hidden fields in your form and every fieled should have a name, When you say `$form.serialize();` it turns it to something like `FirstName=Amr&SecondName=Adel` and so on where `FirstName` is the name of the field and `Amr` is the value of the field, Then you put this serialization into a form of JSON format like `{"data": $form.serialize()}` and add `dataType: "JSON"` to your post request, In your `Insert` function you can get it through `params[:data]` and split it with`&` to be something like `['FirstName=Amr','SecondName=Adel']` and every element split it with `=` so you can get something like this `[['FirstName','Amr'], ['SecondName','Adel']]`.

Hope this helps.